Right align Swift Charts LineMark by default
I haven't found a simple way to align the right a LineMark chart when the X scale is automatic and the X domain is larger than the registered data.
For instance, on this screenshot, I set a X year-long domain, and my oldest data is about 2-3 months ago.

Is it possible, just like the Health data?
Thanks!
EDIT: a MRV with three files: ContentView.swift, MedicalMeasureView.swift and MedicalDataChart.swift :
// ContentView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection: Tab = Tab.home
    
    var body: some View {
        …
    }
}

// MedicalMeasureView.swift

import SwiftUI

enum DataTimeUnit: Int, CaseIterable, Identifiable, Localizable {
    case day = 1
    case week = 7
    case month = 30
    case sixMonths = 180
    case year = 365
    
    var localized: LocalizedStringKey {
        switch self {
            case .day:
                "D"
            case .week:
                "W"
            case .month:
                "M"
            case .sixMonths:
                "6M"
            case .year:
                "Y"
        }
    }
    
    var visibleDomain: Int {
        switch self {
            case .day:
                3600 * 24 * 2
            case .week:
                3600 * 24 * 10
            case .month:
                3600 * 24 * 40
            case .sixMonths:
                3600 * 24 * 40 * 6
            case .year:
                3600 * 24 * 400
        }
    }
    
    var id: Int { self.rawValue }
}

struct MedicalMeasureView: View {
    @Binding var dataType: DataType
    @State var timeUnit: DataTimeUnit = .month
    @State var showAddingNewData: Bool = false
    
    var startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
    var endOfDay = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()))

    var startDisplayedDate: Date {
        let date: Date
        
        switch self.timeUnit {
            default:
                date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -timeUnit.rawValue, to: startOfDay)!
        }
        return date
    }
    
    var endDisplayedDate: Date {
        let date: Date
        
        switch self.timeUnit {
            default:
                date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 0, to: endOfDay!)!
        }
        return date
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Picker("", selection: $timeUnit) {
                    ForEach(DataTimeUnit.allCases) { timeUnit in
                        Text(timeUnit.localized).tag(timeUnit)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Average")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .foregroundStyle(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                        .textCase(.uppercase)

                    HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 5) {
                        if (dataType.latestData != nil) {
                            Text(String(dataType.latestData!.value))
                                .font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded))
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                            + Text(" \(dataType.unit)")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .fontWeight(.regular)
                                .foregroundStyle(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                    Text(startDisplayedDate...endDisplayedDate)
                        .font(.callout)
                        .foregroundStyle(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                }.padding(.horizontal)
                
                MedicalDataChart(dataType: $dataType, timeUnit: $timeUnit)
                    .frame(height: 300)
                 
            }
            .background(.background.secondary)
            .padding(.top)
            
            
            List {
                Section {
                    Button {
                        // $showAddingNewData.toggle()
                        showAddingNewData.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        ZStack {
                            Text("Add new data")
                                .foregroundStyle(Color("ContrastColor"))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .contentMargins(.top, 20)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.background.secondary)
        .navigationTitle(dataType.name)
        .sheet(isPresented: $showAddingNewData) {
            MedicalDataSheet(dataName: "Name", unit: "kg")
        }
    }
}

#Preview("Medical item") {
    NavigationStack {
        MedicalMeasureView(dataType: .constant(DataType(
            id: 1,
            name: "Weight",
            unit: "kg",
            data: [
                AnimalData(id: 1, value: 28, date: Date(from: "2024-10-02")),
                AnimalData(id: 1, value: 20, date: Date(from: "2024-11-02")),
                AnimalData(id: 1, value: 25, date: Date(from: "2024-12-02")),
                AnimalData(id: 1, value: 24, date: Date())
            ]
        )))
    }
}

// MedicalDataChart.swift

import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct MedicalDataChart: View {
    @Binding var dataType: DataType
    @Binding var timeUnit: DataTimeUnit
    
    var startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
    var endOfDay = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()))
    
    var startDisplayedDate: Date {
        let date: Date
        
        switch self.timeUnit {
            default:
                date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -timeUnit.rawValue, to: startOfDay)!
        }
        return date
    }
    
    var endDisplayedDate: Date {
        let date: Date
        
        switch self.timeUnit {
            default:
                date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 0, to: endOfDay!)!
        }
        return date
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(dataType.data) { measure in
                LineMark(
                    x: .value("X", measure.date, unit: .day),
                    y: .value("Y", measure.value)
                )
                .symbol(.circle)
                .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
                .foregroundStyle(Color("ContrastColor"))
            }
        }
        
        /*
         .chartXAxis {
             // AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .day, count: 7))
             AxisMarks(values: .automatic) { value in
                 if let date = value.as(Date.self) {
                     AxisValueLabel {
                        Text(date, format: .dateTime.day())
                    }
                    AxisGridLine()
                    AxisTick()
                 }
             }
         }
         */
        .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)
        // .chartScrollTargetBehavior(.valueAligned(unit: 1))
        .chartScrollPosition(initialX: endOfDay!)
        // .chartXScale(domain: .automatic(includesZero: false))
        // .chartXScale(domain: startDisplayedDate...endDisplayedDate)
        .chartXVisibleDomain(length: self.timeUnit.visibleDomain)
        .chartYScale(domain: .automatic(includesZero: true))
        // .chartYScale(domain: 15...30)
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.bottom)
    }
}

#Preview {
    MedicalDataChart(
        dataType: .constant(DataType(
            id: 1,
            name: "Weight",
            unit: "kg",
            data: [
                AnimalData(id: 1, value: 28, date: Date(from: "2024-10-02")),
                AnimalData(id: 1, value: 20, date: Date(from: "2024-11-02")),
                AnimalData(id: 1, value: 25, date: Date(from: "2024-12-02")),
                AnimalData(id: 1, value: 24, date: Date())
            ]
        )),
        timeUnit: .constant(DataTimeUnit.month)
    )
}


Please show a [mre]. What do you mean by "when the X scale is automatic and the X domain is larger than the registered data"?

I added a MVP, I hope this is fine. I mean when I use the "year" view, and my oldest data was three months ago.
I would like to know if there is an easy way to have my data on the right, i.e. on this view that the right date of the domain is tomorrow, and the left one is one year ago. For now, the left date is the one from the oldest data, and the right one is the oldest + 1 year.
